# how to display pdf file in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, itext

I want to show a pdf file when pressing the button or link,this is the location for pdf file :  /opt/tomcat/pdf/test.pdf

please help me , I 've tried many ways but can not

I heve created a link like this

```
<a href="/admin-teknikal/viewpdf/${asas.foto_istlsi}">${asas.foto_istlsi}</a>
```

when the link is clicked , the pdf file will appear

this my controller

```
@Controller
public class viewpdf {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/viewpdf/{foto_istlsi}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry,
                @PathVariable("foto_istlsi") String pdf) {
            registry
              .addResourceHandler("/files/**")
              .addResourceLocations("file:/opt/tomcat/pdf/"+pdf);
         }


}
```

but I getting error like this

```
Apr 13, 2016 11:19:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/admin-teknikal] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry.<init>()] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Comment: There it nothing special (and specific to Spring MVC): you need to serve this file and properly set headers (at least, `Content-Type`). Internet has many articles about serving static files (most of the time, images).

Comment: I have updated my post , I followed your advice but get an error , I am a beginner in the spring . I need your help

Comment: You're configuring registry at the wrong place (it shouldn't be in the controller). See the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment there is nothing special about using Spring MVC to serve files from the filesystem (this is [how I do it myself](https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/9b5cb78de8125dc3d6ab9cef1fbcc05fe2a2b52e/src/main/java/ru/mystamps/web/controller/ImageController.java#L40-L60); idea based on [`ImageServlet`](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/04/imageservlet.html) from @balusc). But if you really want to use Spring MVC-specific solution, you could configure resource handler for that:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
      .addResourceHandler("/pdf/**")
      .addResourceLocations("file:/opt/tomcat/pdf/");
 }
```

More information you could find in the blog post from @eugen: [Serve Static Resources with Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources)